# Boto3 ListObject Forbidden for Admin User

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I have been trying to write a small script to download to lambda /tmp all the content of a S3 folder. To do this I need to list all Objects in a specific bucket. Unfortunately I keep getting the following error;

> An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Here is how I try to download all the files from a folder:

```
#initialize S3
try:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
        aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('S3USERACCESSKEY'),
        aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('S3USERSECRETKEY')
    )
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
        aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('S3USERACCESSKEY'),
        aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('S3USERSECRETKEY')
    )
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Could not connect to s3 bucket: " + str(e))

#Function to download whole folders from s3
for s3_key in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=os.getenv('S3BUCKETNAME'))['Contents']:
    s3_object = s3_key['Key']
    if not s3_object.endswith("/"):
        s3_client.download_file('bucket', s3_object, s3_object)
    else:
        import os
        if not os.path.exists(s3_object):
            os.makedirs(s3_object)
```

The access keys above have full admin rights: 
[image]

**EDIT**

Still no success after removing my manual keys, here are the right i attached to Lambda:

[image]

Here is the actual error from cloudwatch:

[image]

The code now looks like so:

```
#initialize S3
    try:
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    except Exception as e:
          [....]
```

Seems like "Forbidden" might be another issue then permission but I can't find any doc on it.

Comment: This is not  a lambda right?

Comment: @Spiff It does run in lambda

Comment: If you have a look at the permission scheme i have attached on the picutre i have full admin rights to everything on aws, and i added on top of that full access to S3.

Comment: Since it executes inside a lambda,  there's no need to use an access key, just  attach the IAM role to lambda

Comment: Se my updated answer

Comment: Do you have any S3 bucket policy attached to that bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the access key belongs to the user with the IAM role that has rights to access the s3 bucket.
If you run from lambda, there's no need to use an access key, just  attach the IAM role to lambda

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/accessing-resources.html

Did you import boto?
Try to run execute only this:

**UPDATE**

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
  print(bucket.name)
```

Comment: It does i have checked.

Comment: I have added the roles to lambda no success, see my EDIT above.

Comment: If boto3 was not imported i would get a different error message, something along the lines of "boto3 is not defined"